# Which sandboxed web environment for a kiosk?

Tags: lamp, kiosk, kiosk-mode

We have been asked to develop an application for a museum that will serve content via a kiosk to the public. Control is mouse, not touch screen.

There will be animation in the UI, video and audio. We've looked at Silverlight and Flash but are leaning toward HTML5 for easier workflow and more flexibility.

We can live with serialized sources of data but would prefer a database, so we need a web environment like XAMPP. I worry about memory management with an environment like that. We won't have any access to the system after the initial install, so the system should be able to run a long time without being recycled.

What is a good environment for a system like this? We don't care too much about the the language used. PHP would be easier, but robustness of the guest on the Windows host is more important.

Comment: You should strongly consider setting up a linux box for such an environment.  If you want something that will run a long time without restarts, crashes, etc., linux is way, way, WAY better than Windows.  And, LAMP setups come as part of many linux installs such as Ubuntu.

Comment: We're not in control of the hardware. Further, the organization has limited IT support, so Linux is out of the question.

Comment: Bummer.  Then I would recommend [manually setting up a WAMP environment](http://webdevcodex.com/tutorial-installing-apache2-php5-mysql5-phpmyadmin3-windows-7-vista/).  It's a bit more involved than XAMPP, but sheds some of the overhead that XAMPP comes with.

Answer (score 0):

I develop the opensource [Webconverger](http://www.webconverger.com/) distribution for your use case.

You develop the Web application and Webconverger reliably hosts it for the public patrons of the museum.

You don't need to know any Linux. It can be used as a turnkey solution and you configure the machine via a Web control panel.